# Repair corrupted text file using shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I have a corrupted file that looks like this:-

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|col12|col13|col14|col15
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|
h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
```

which should actually look like this:-

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|col12|col13|col14|col15
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
```

In this file, I have 15 columns which are separated by pipes'|'.
The 3rd record in the file is split into two records which should actually be a single record.

I have tried this code:-
1.`sed -e '/^$/d' source_file.txt|tr '\n' ' ' > temp.txt` - which should append all records in single line
2.`awk -v RS='[\n|]' '{a=$0;getline b;getline c;getline d;getline e;getline f: getline g;getline h;getline i;getline j;getline k;getline m;getline n;getline o;print a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o}' OFS='|' temp.txt > source_file.txt` - which should result in the required output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feels like a job for awk.  Accumulate a count of entries, and emit a newline when you have 15:

```
$ cat input
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|col12|col13|col14|col15
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|
d|e|f|g|
h|i|j
|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|
h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d
|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
$ awk '{c += NF; printf "%s", $0} c >= 15 {printf "\n"; c = 0}' FS=\| input
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|col12|col13|col14|col15
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach, which looks for lines that don't have 14 pipes and appends the next line of input to the pattern space before trying again:

```
$ sed ':a; /\([^|]*|\)\{14\}/!{N; s/\n//; ba}' foo.txt
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10|col11|col12|col13|col14|col15
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
a|b|c|d|e|f|g|h|i|j|k|l|||
```